# how to identify rootpath for application server?

Tags: c#, jquery

In my .net web application I create a blank solution and add website and class library into it. All the website pages are in UI folder, so when I use

```
'<%=ResolveUrl("~") %>'
```

in javascript, it returns '/UI/', but in application server I set website root at UI folder, so '<%=ResolveUrl("~") %>' returns '/'. The problem here is, when I call AjaxPages under UI/AjaxPages/ folder it only works at local, it does not work at application server. The code I use is

```
var root='<%=ResolveUrl("~") %>';
$.post(root+"AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx",....)...
```

Even I use

```
var path='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx") %>';
$.post(path,....)
```

It still does not work in application server, but works local.
I really have no idea what's wrong here. Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var path = '<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx") %>';
```

Comment: Doesn't work, even worse, the code does not work in local either.

Comment: can you just alert the path and see what it gives?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<%=Url.Content("~~/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx") %>
```

or:

```
<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx") %>
```

Comment: UrlHelper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx